# Encoding Apostrophe with JSON.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, json.net

Say I have a class like

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public MyTestClass()
    {
        Testing = "check ' out";
    }
    public string Testing { get; set; }
}
```

And JavascriptSerializer/JsonNet serializers like :

```
public IHtmlString ToJsonNet(object value)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
}

public IHtmlString ToJson(object value)
{
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return new MvcHtmlString(json.Serialize(value));
}
```

Then in a view I have

```
 @(Serializers.ToJsonNet(new MyTestClass()))
 @(Serializers.ToJson(new MyTestClass()))
```

The JsonNet will return {"Testing":"check ' out"}, while the JavascriptSerializer will return {"Testing":"check \u0027 out"}. I wish to create a javascript object like

```
var model = $.parseJSON('@jsonString');
```

But this only works if the apostrophe is encoded. Otherwise, the apostrophe makes my javacript look like

```
var model = $.parseJSON('{"Testing":"check ' out"}');
```

which fails because the inserted apostrophe makes `parseJSON` escape my string too early.

JavascriptSerializer encodes the apostrophe as \u0027 by default while JSON.NET (which I want to use) does not. How can I change JSON.NET to do this? Is there a setting I'm missing? Is there a different way I can parse my JSON string into javascript where the apostrophe is OK?

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue with JSON.NET?

Answer (score 1):

The following answer indicates that the two should be equivalent.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5022386/1388165

If it is the parseJSON call failing, perhaps double quotes instead of single quotes in the argument would help.

Comment: Because the jsonstring contains both double quotes and single quotes, using either of them in the parseJson currently causes a failure because it escapes the jsonString early.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping the apostrophe with a "\"?

Something like `Testing = "check \' out";`

---

You should also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12042302/2182203) post, there seem to be some interesting answers for you here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> ```
> {"Testing":"check \u0027 out"}
> ```

Comment: When I paste text into an html text area from Microsoft Word and then use that value to serialize it in C#, the apostrophe does not get serialized as \u0027 but instead it remains as "'" character. Any thoughts?