# Javascript Escape from Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

The [Json.NET homepage](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) says the project started out as :

> a couple of static methods for escaping JavaScript strings

Do these methods still exist?  I'm aware that [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) can do this, but I'm after a one liner to do this.

`SerializeObject` can serialize a single string (which escapes it) but it returns the quotes

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@"hi bud's  \no way\");
```

Returns: `"hi bud's  \\no way\\"`

Comment: Look like the same http://stackoverflow.com/q/12042302/605240

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a nice one-liner solution, but it has only been in the framework since 4.0.  Would be nice to have something similar in Json.NET I can use on < 4.0 projects.

[`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784638.aspx) example:

```
HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(@"hi bud's  \no way\")
```

Returns: `hi bud\u0027s  \\no way\\`