# Deserialize json string that contains singlequote using c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a json string that contains a string literal as value of one of the object - `PostData`.

```
string json = "{\"PostData\": '{\"LastName\": \"O Corner\",\"FirstName\":\"Mark\",\"Address\":\"123 James St\"}'}";
```

I am trying to deserialize the json using:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

then, I can use my json string value of `PostData` like:

```
obj["PostData"].ToString()
```

But, as soon as I get the data with single quotes in it, like:

```
string json = "{\"PostData\": '{\"LastName\": \"O' Corner\",\"FirstName\":\"Mark\",\"Address\":\"123 James St\"}'}";
```

I get exception on deserialization. How can I escape the single quote?

I have checked SO for similar issues but didn't get any thing working. I also tried one of the solution mentioned int his [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042302/serializing-strings-containing-apostrophes-with-json-net):

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    StringEscapeHandling =  StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
};

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

But, I get Newtonsoft doesnot contain defination for `StringEscapeHandling`.

Also, tried to escape the singlequote with in the string with `\`:
`'{\"LastName\": \"O\' Corner\",\"FirstName\":\"Mark\",\"Address\":\"123 James St\"}'` which didn't work either.

Comment: I assume the best choice is to carefully serialize your object first. Which is Newtonsoft.Json version used? `StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml` exists in latest `8.0.3` version and works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, it might be worth noting that the JSON [syntax](http://json.org/) uses single quotes where you have used double quotes. Here is a guide for proper syntax:

[image: JSON Syntax]

Now unfortunately JSON does not allow the use of single quotes like that, but we can use the unicode `\u0027` for an apostrophe and make use of JSON's serializer settings, as you have already done. So your original string:

```
string json = "{\"PostData\": '{\"LastName\": \"O' Corner\",\"FirstName\":\"Mark\",\"Address\":\"123 James St\"}'}";
```

becomes:

```
string json = "{'PostData': {'LastName': 'O\u0027 Corner','FirstName':'Mark','Address':'123 James St'}}"
```

This is assuming that you are parsing a string literal, otherwise you would need to escape the unicode to give:

```
string json = "{'PostData': {'LastName': 'O\\u0027 Corner','FirstName':'Mark','Address':'123 James St'}}"
```

Comment: escaping the unicode worked for us i.e. `\u0027` to `\\u0027`

Comment: How do I replace a single quote to this unicode in the value of a property but not the entire json? because I have dynamic json string in variable.